# How can I convert a UTC date to ISOString format without changing the date/time?

Tags: javascript

Here's the code that I have so far. The current UTC Time = **1:22pm**

```
var now = new Date();
var now_utc = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(), now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes(), now.getUTCSeconds());
var isoDate1 = now_utc.toISOString();

now >>> Wed Jul 06 2016 21:22:20 GMT+0800
now_utc >>>  Wed Jul 06 2016 13:22:20 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)
isoDate1 >>> "2016-07-06T05:22:20.000Z"
```

My problem is I expected and need, the isoDate1 to look like this:

```
2016-07-06T13:22:20.000Z
```

It seems that now_utc is correct but when converted to the iso format then it changes.

Can anyone give me any advice on this?

Answer (score 1):

`new Date(...)` will always construct it with the date/time passed as being **local** time, and `toISOString` gives you both the ISO format, but also the UTC equivalent of the local time that you constructed, hence the behaviour you're seeing - note how your output of `now_utc` is showing `GMT+0800` - this means it's a local time, offset from GMT/UTC by +8 hours.

You should simply be able to do this to get the current UTC time as an ISO string:

```
(new Date()).toISOString(); //"2016-07-06T13:39:50.432Z"
```